# Can VTune work without sampling driver and perf?

Tags: profiling, intel-vtune

The SEP drivers weren't built and weren't installed:

```
hekto@ubuntu:/opt/intel/vtune_amplifier_xe/sepdk/src$ sudo ./insmod-sep -q
pax driver is not loaded.
socperf2_0 driver is not loaded.
sep4_0 driver is not loaded.
vtsspp driver is not loaded.
```

The Perf tool also wasn't built correctly (the kernel is customized one):

```
hekto@ubuntu:/opt/intel/vtune_amplifier_xe/sepdk/src$ perf -v
WARNING: perf not found for kernel 3.18.41-test
```

But - the VTune actually works, I can see profiling results. What kind of sampling is being used in this case? I don't see anything about that in the VTune GUI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It uses user mode sampling by injecting into the app and setting profiling timers for each thread and then capturing IP and stack in signal handlers. see more https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/544072